# Bypass virus scanner that blocks fonts

Tags: penetration-testing, virus-scanning

This isn't much a programming language but i hope the community can help, at a place i work every file that i want to insert to our closed network must pass scans, and the scan automatically disables bringing in fonts, and html/js/css. What i did to import js was just copy the code into a doc file and import, that works, but what can i do to fool the program to import fonts? If i open the ttf file as a txt, can i copy the contents to a word document and rebuild file? Also putting the file in a winrar thats in another winrar doesent work either.

Comment: Maybe there's a good reason those security measures are in place. Does your employer know you are doing this?

Comment: Yes, he said if i find a way to import the data then i should do it.

Comment: Have the data you need to transfer wrapped up in a DRM privacy container. It'll trick the AV because it will essentially compose the file as a privacy-protected media file.

Comment: (Depending on the scanner policy) an encrypted archive file might help (would recommend 7zip with archive header encryption `-p -mhe=on`).

Comment: @vlp How do i do this? what does the extension of the archive need to be because the only archive viewer i have in the network is Winrar, can i decompress 7zip with winrar? what extension is it and how do i add these headers...